# Como Utilizar mascaras no Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e estou passando por uma dificuldade na hora de usar o Ajax, junto a um plugin [inputMask](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Easy-jQuery-Input-Mask-Plugin-inputmask.html). Tenho algumas máscaras configuradas, mas na hora de utilizar ela nas requisições do Ajax, elas não funcionam e não sei que direção tomar.

Função do inputMask:

```
$('.input-cpf').inputmask({"mask": "999.999.999-99", "placeholder":"_"});
```

Meu input:

```
<input name="cpf" type="text" class="form-control input-cpf">
```

Alguem conseguiria me ajudar? qual direção preciso tomar?

Comment: O campo CPF está ficando sem a mascará durante a submição do formulário com AJAX?

Comment: Você pode detalhar melhor o que não está funcionando?

Comment: Primeiro, o elemento input já está renderizado no DOM antes de você chamar o inputMas? Outro ponto este input está retornando do AJAX, pois você pode está carregando o inputMask em um elemento que ainda não está no DOM e quando ele é retornado via AJAX a função do plugin não irá reconhecer o elemento recém inserido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver.
Eu coloquei um evento de click dentro do elemento, que chamava uma função:

```
<input name="cpf" onclick="ajaxCPF()" type="text" class="form-control cpf-ajax">
```

E a função basicamente aplicava a mascara, já que como tinha dito ela não era carregada no DOM

```
function ajaxCPF(){
    $('.cpf-ajax').inputmask({"mask": "999.999.999-99", "placeholder":"_"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como podemos ver abaixo, a máscara está adicionada ao valor do input normalmente.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input-cpf').inputmask({
    mask: "999.999.999-99"
  });

  $('.input-cpf').keypress(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>


<input name="cpf" type="text" class="form-control input-cpf" placeholder="CPF">
```

Comment: Marcus Italo, acredito que seja essa a situação, eu sou bem fraco com javascript, ainda mais Ajax. A mascára funciona em outra páginas que tem o refresh, mas nessa tela q ta via AJAX ela n funciona, como se não tivesse sendo carregada.